# String index out of range inside of a method: Java

Tags: java, indexing

I was writing some code for my class and I ran into this error, String index out of range. I checked to see if it might be the string = null but that's not the case. I'm guessing it has to do with my if statement in the method but I couldn't find how to fix it anywhere. Any help is appreciated, thank you very much!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Occurences { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int check = 0;
         char characterInput = ' ';
         do {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
            String input = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter a character to find it's occurence in the string: ");
            characterInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
            int i = count(input, characterInput);

            System.out.println(characterInput + ", is in " + input + ", " + i + " times.");
            System.out.println("To continue enter any number, to exit enter -1: ");
            check = scan.nextInt();
         } while (check != -1);
    }
   public static int count(String input, char characterInput) {
      int cnt = 0;
      int j = input.length();
      while (j > 0) { 
         if (input.charAt(j) == characterInput) { 
         cnt += 1;
         }
         j--;
         }
     return cnt;
   }
}
```

Comment: The last character is on index `length()-1`, because the first index is `0`.

Comment: Java index out of range errors happen when you try to access array indices that don't exist. It is important to note that Java arrays start with an index of 0. See if you can figure it out based on this info. I don't want to give away the answer... it won't help you learn.

Comment: int j = input.length()-1;

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I ended up switching j to 0 and increment up which worked but I do understand where the error happened.

Comment: @GabrielTomasetto, see my answer below, I explained why what you did worked. if my answer helps explain it for you, please consider upvoting it and accepting it as an answer. =] thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error happens on line 21: `int j = input.length()`, as others mentioned in the comments, java, and most programming languages, index strings and array types by zero-indexing - starting from zero. So you have to either `1)` start counting at 0 or `2)` stop counting at one-less-than the length of the string(array), which is why line 21 needs to be either:

`int j = input.length()-1;`

or as you solved it using method 1:

setting `int j=0;`